# accessing json not showing output

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am doing `json_encode(simplexml_load_file($xmlpath))`
I am getting the output as below.

```
{"@attributes":{
        "source":"Tas Football",
        "version":"4.14.00",
        "generated":"8\/20\/2013"
    },
    "venue":{
        "@attributes":{
            "visname":"Book"
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this json in javascript and storing it in `data` variable
I am trying to access the elements but not getting any success.

```
alert(data.venue.@attributes.visname);
```

The above code doesn't show any output.

The ajax code for this is below:

```
$.get("fetchXml.php?file=../../xml/wk1/BookerTWashington_Douglas.xml",function (data){
                data=$.parseJSON(data);
                alert(data.venue.@attributes.visname);
    });
```

Comment: How are you doing this in javascript? I assume you are using ajax? Can you show us your code in javascript part. Well maybe you had the same issue but if you are using ajax, make sure you made the dataType :"json".

Comment: How do you get your php variable to JS in the first place?

Comment: I have made an edit and shown the ajax for it

Comment: Try `data.venue['@attributes'].visname`?

Comment: Why don't you just return the XML to the client, instead of converting it to JSON?

Comment: parsing json on javascript is relatively easy than xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @ in the variable name is invalid:
JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. This means that a variable name such as myCounter is different from the variable name MYCounter. Variable names can be of any length. The rules for creating legal variable names are as follows:

The first character must be an ASCII letter (either uppercase or lowercase), or an underscore (_) character. Note that a number cannot be used as the first character.

Subsequent characters must be letters, numbers, or underscores (_).

The variable name must not be a reserved word.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/67defydd(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: the php function json_encode() has automatically added the @attribute.
Do you suggest the I must replace all the @ with blank.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data.venue['@attributes'].visname
```